# how to write this in Verbatim literal

Tags: c#, string, verbatim-string

I have an audio file name with spaces

```
String filename = @"c:\users\me\desktop\this is audio.mp3";
```

say i want to open this file through cmd using external process,to open it i need the path to be like this : `c:\users\me\desktop\"this is audio.mp3"` (With quotes)

any ideas how to convert it to valid verbatim literal ?

I've tried the following:

```
String file2 = @"c:\users\me\desktop\""this is audio.mp3""";
```

but i got this

c:\users\me\desktop\\this is audio.mp3"

Comment: That is correct when displayed in the debugger's inspector.

Comment: `@"""c:\users\me\desktop\this is audio.mp3"""` in *C#* is same as `"\"c:\users\me\desktop\this is audio.mp3\""` in *C#* which turn is same as `"c:\users\me\desktop\this is audio.mp3"` in *normal text*.

Comment: What you see in the watch is not what you get = WYSIWINWYG. Go ahead and try harder — output that string to a console window.

Answer (score 1):

You have escaped correctly.

The debugger is showing you a non literal string.

```
@"""c:\users\me\desktop\this is audio.mp3"""
```

And:

```
"\"c:\\users\\me\\desktop\\this is audio.mp3\""
```

Are identical, as far as the compiler/debugger are concerned.

They both produce a string containing: `"c:\users\me\desktop\this is audio.mp3"` (with the double quotes embedded).

Comment: but i still can't open that file !

Comment: @Howa - What exception are you getting? Are you certain the file is there and that the running process has permissions to it?

Comment: hmm, say i want it like this c:\users\me\desktop\"this is audio.mp3", how to implement it using verbatim literal ?

Comment: @Howa - `@"c:\users\me\desktop\""this is audio.mp3"""`.

Comment: but \" in verbatim literal means \ not "

Comment: @Howa - Yes. But to get a `"`, you need to double it, as I did. The `\ ` is the _directory separator_ in that string.

Comment: ok i know that, but look at `"c:\users\me\desktop\""this is audio.mp3"""`, after desktop\""this is audio.mp3""", it'll be like this desktop\\"this is audio.mp3"

Comment: @Howa - What makes you say that?

Comment: sir i got it :), but in verbatim literal to get \ i have to write `@\"` , the problem is with the path, `"c:\users\me\desktop\""this is audio.mp3"""` , after `desktop`\ i need the `"` not \

Comment: it wont give **"** because there's \" which gives \